# Blazor Multithreaded Javascript

Tags: javascript, .net, multithreading, blazor, .net-6.0

I am trying to perform two tedious Javascript tasks in parallel with Blazor WebAssembly in .NET 6. My current code looks like this:

```
task1 = Task.Run(async () =>
{
  try
  {     
    await JSInProcessRuntime.InvokeAsync<int>("BuildTablesOne", new object[] {data1});
  }
  catch (Exception exc)
  {
    await JSInProcessRuntime.InvokeAsync<object>("console.log", exc.Message);
  }
});

task2 = Task.Run(async () =>
{
   try
   {     
      await JSInProcessRuntime.InvokeAsync<int>("BuildTablesTwo", new object[] {data2});
   }
   catch (Exception exc)
   {
      await JSInProcessRuntime.InvokeAsync<object>("console.log", exc.Message);
   }
});

await Task.WhenAll(task1, task2);
```

These tasks seemingly don't run in parallel as I'd like. I estimate that each of the tasks takes around 2 seconds to finish separately. Totaling 4 seconds of execution time running after each other. In my ideal scenario I would be able to run these both in parallel for a total execution time of 2 seconds. Now I learned that Javascript does not have support for Multithreading but then I also came across WebWorkers and similar concepts and was thinking that maybe Blazor WASM has mechanisms to hook into those new concepts and tools somehow.

Is the above what I am trying to do even achievable, and if yes what can I change in the code to make this fully run in parallel?

Comment: JavaScript does not run in parallel, and cannot run in parallel. You will have to do your multithreaded work in C# instead. Since this is Blazor, it is recommended you port the JavaScript to C#. Is there a reason you are doing work in JavaScript?

Comment: The reason why I am doing the work in JavaScript is because those methods are using third party methods that are only available in JavaScript

Comment: Multithreading is not implemented in mono yet. Blazor multithreading is blocked by it. See [this](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/17730) and [this](https://github.com/mono/mono/issues/12453). It is currently planned for .NET 7 which will release in November.

Comment: Thanks @Grizzlly, I have just updated to .NET 7 Preview 2 and trying to figure out if this feature is already working in .NET 7 or not. Do you happen to know? Seems ambiguous from the links you sent. Thanks a lot! If its implement, will my code above work out of the box you think?

Comment: It is not available yet. Take a look at this [comment](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/17730#issuecomment-1043597775).

Comment: Is this possible yet? If yes, how? @Grizzlly

Comment: @Smith5727 https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/44984